# way for multiplication of these tensors with gradients

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, tensor

I have a function with two inputs: heat maps and feature maps.
The heatmaps have a shape of `(20, 14, 64, 64)` and the feature maps have a shape of `(20, 64, 64, 64)`. Where `20` is the batch size and `14` is the number of key points. Both heatmaps and feature maps have spatial dimensions of `64x64` and the featuremaps have `64` channels (on the second dimension).

Now I need to multiply each heatmap by each channel of the feature maps. So the first heatmap has to be multiplied by all `64` channels of the feature maps. The second with all channels, and so on.

After that, I should have a tensor of shape `(20, 14, 64, 64, 64)` on which I need to apply global max-pooling.

The problem is now that I can't create a new tensor to do that, because the gradients of the heatmaps and feature maps must be preserved.

My actual (slow and not-gradient-keeping) code is:

```
def get_keypoint_representation(self, heatmaps, features):
    heatmaps = heatmaps[0]
    pool = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(features.shape[2])
    features = features[:, None, :, :, :]
    features = features.expand(-1, 14, -1, -1, -1).clone()

    for i in range(self.cfg.SINGLE_GPU_BATCH_SIZE):
        for j in range(self.cfg.NUM_JOINTS):
            for k in range(features.shape[2]):
                features[i][j][k] = torch.matmul(heatmaps[i][j], features[i][j][k])

    gmp = features.amax(dim=(-1, -2))
    return gmp
```

Overview of the task:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a tensor of heatmaps `hm` shaped `(b, k, h, w)` and a feature tensor `fm` shaped `(b, c, h, w)`.

You can perform such an operation with a single [`einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html) operator

```
>>> z = torch.einsum('bkhw,bchw->bkchw', hm, FM)
>>> z.shape
torch.Size([20, 14, 64, 64, 64])
```

Then follow with a max-pooling operation over the spatial dimensions using [`amax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.amax.html):

```
 >>> gmp = z.amax(dim=(-1,-2))
 >>> gmp.shape
 torch.Size([20, 14, 64])
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot shorter than mine version ^^ But I get differnt results from your and mine version. So im not sure, that einsum does what I want.  The tensors have to be multiplicated, but einsum sums it?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example with both inputs and the expected output?

Comment: I don't know if this example covers all cases, but:
hm: (1, 1, 3, 3) with values (2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9) and ft: (1, 2, 3, 3) with values (1, 6, 4, 7, 2, 8, 5, 9, 3) and (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9). Result should be res: (1, 2, 3, 3) with values (2, 24, 24, 7, 6, 40, 35, 72, 27) and (2, 8, 18, 4, 15, 30, 49, 64, 81)

Comment: That's because I max pooled along the spatial dimensions, this seems to be the case in your figure. Are you sure this is what you want? Shouldn't your resulting tensor be `batch_size` x  `channel` x `keypoints`?

Comment: No, the max_pooling works :) The output should have dimension batch_size x keypoints x channels. So each keypoint is represented by 64 values.

Comment: So why is your expected output `(1, 2, 3, 3)`?

Comment: Oh, i found a mistake in my second comment... the output-size of the multiplication should be (1, 1, 2, 3, 3) and not (1, 2, 3, 3)

Comment: Ok, but I am referring to the spatial locations, in the example you give above (in your comment) you have inputs and an output with equal spatial dimensions. How do you explain this having applied the max pool operation?

Comment: The output I mentioned in the comment above was without global max-pooling. The output (1, 1, 2, 3, 3) is just the output of the multiplication.

Comment: Can you give the output **after** the max-pooling operation then? Btw, the `einsum` call above will return the desired output **before** max-pooling is applied.

Comment: Shape after multiplication: (20, 14, 64, 64, 64). Shape after max-pooling: (20, 14, 64).
einsum returnes the desired output-shape, but not the correct values.

Comment: Pleas try with your example: `hm=torch.tensor([2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]).reshape(1, 1, 3, 3)`, `ft=torch.tensor([1, 6, 4, 7, 2, 8, 5, 9, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]).reshape(1, 2, 3, 3)`: `torch.einsum('bkhw,bchw->bkchw', hm, ft)` will return the desired intermediate result.

Comment: Worked. Sorry, was a bit confused :D Thank you for your help and your patience :)

Comment: No worries, I'm glad it worked out for you ;)